# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory in training with pytorch "Pose2Seg"

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu

When I run this code https://github.com/erezposner/Pose2Seg

And I made all steps in this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/detection-free-human-instance-segmentation-using-pose2seg-and-pytorch-72f48dc4d23e

but I have this error in cuda:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 128.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.57 GiB already allocated; 74.77 MiB free; 2.85 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) (malloc at ..\c10\cuda\CUDACachingAllocator.cpp:289) (no backtrace available)
```

**How can I solve this?**

```
(base) C:\Users\ASUS\Pose2Seg>python train.py
06-23 07:30:01 ===========> loading model <===========
total params in model is 334, in pretrained model is 336, init 334
06-23 07:30:03 ===========> loading data <===========
loading annotations into memory...
Done (t=4.56s)
creating index...
index created!
06-23 07:30:08 ===========> set optimizer <===========
06-23 07:30:08 ===========>   training    <===========
C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:2796: UserWarning: nn.functional.upsample is deprecated. Use nn.functional.interpolate instead.
  warnings.warn("nn.functional.upsample is deprecated. Use nn.functional.interpolate instead.")
C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:2973: UserWarning: Default upsampling behavior when mode=bilinear is changed to align_corners=False since 0.4.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details.
  "See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details.".format(mode))
C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3289: UserWarning: Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed to align_corners=False since 1.3.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of grid_sample for details.
  warnings.warn("Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed "
C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3226: UserWarning: Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed to align_corners=False since 1.3.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of grid_sample for details.
  warnings.warn("Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed "
06-23 07:30:13 Epoch: [0][0/56599]      Lr: [6.68e-05]  Time 4.228 (4.228)      Data 0.028 (0.028)      loss 0.85738 (0.85738)
06-23 07:30:22 Epoch: [0][10/56599]     Lr: [6.813333333333334e-05]     Time 0.847 (1.280)      Data 0.012 (0.051)      loss 0.44195 (0.71130)
06-23 07:30:33 Epoch: [0][20/56599]     Lr: [6.946666666666667e-05]     Time 0.882 (1.180)      Data 0.045 (0.037)      loss 0.41523 (0.60743)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 157, in <module>
    optimizer, epoch, iteration)
  File "train.py", line 74, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 198, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 100, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 128.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.57 GiB already allocated; 74.77 MiB free; 2.85 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) (malloc at ..\c10\cuda\CUDACachingAllocator.cpp:289)
(no backtrace available)
```

> cudatoolkit == 10.1.243

python3.6.5

The version of libs:

```
>>> import tensorflow
2020-06-23 09:45:01.840827: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__version__
'2.3.1'
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.5.1'
>>> import torchvision
>>> torchvision.__version__
'0.6.1'
>>> import pycocotools
```

train.py code

```
import os
import sys
import time
import logging
import argparse
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch
import torch.utils.data

from lib.averageMeter import AverageMeters
from lib.logger import colorlogger
from lib.timer import Timers
from lib.averageMeter import AverageMeters
from lib.torch_utils import adjust_learning_rate
import os
from modeling.build_model import Pose2Seg
from datasets.CocoDatasetInfo import CocoDatasetInfo, annToMask
from test import test

NAME = "release_base"

# Set `LOG_DIR` and `SNAPSHOT_DIR`


def setup_logdir():
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S", time.localtime())
    LOGDIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs', '%s_%s' % (NAME, timestamp))
    SNAPSHOTDIR = os.path.join(
        os.getcwd(), 'snapshot', '%s_%s' % (NAME, timestamp))
    if not os.path.exists(LOGDIR):
        os.makedirs(LOGDIR)
    if not os.path.exists(SNAPSHOTDIR):
        os.makedirs(SNAPSHOTDIR)
    return LOGDIR, SNAPSHOTDIR


LOGDIR, SNAPSHOTDIR = setup_logdir()

# Set logging
logger = colorlogger(log_dir=LOGDIR, log_name='train_logs.txt')

# Set Global Timer
timers = Timers()

# Set Global AverageMeter
averMeters = AverageMeters()


def train(model, dataloader, optimizer, epoch, iteration):
    # switch to train mode
    model.train()

    averMeters.clear()
    end = time.time()
    for i, inputs in enumerate(dataloader):
        averMeters['data_time'].update(time.time() - end)
        iteration += 1

        lr = adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, iteration, BASE_LR=0.0002,
                                  WARM_UP_FACTOR=1.0/3, WARM_UP_ITERS=1000,
                                  STEPS=(0, 14150*15, 14150*20), GAMMA=0.1)

        # forward
        outputs = model(**inputs)

        # loss
        loss = outputs

        # backward
        averMeters['loss'].update(loss.data.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # measure elapsed time
        averMeters['batch_time'].update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()

        if i % 10 == 0:
            logger.info('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}]\t'
                        'Lr: [{3}]\t'
                        'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                        'Data {data_time.val:.3f} ({data_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                        'loss {loss.val:.5f} ({loss.avg:.5f})\t'
                        .format(
                            epoch, i, len(dataloader), lr,
                            batch_time=averMeters['batch_time'], data_time=averMeters['data_time'],
                            loss=averMeters['loss'])
                        )

        if i % 10000 == 0:
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(
                SNAPSHOTDIR, '%d_%d.pkl' % (epoch, i)))
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(
                SNAPSHOTDIR, 'last.pkl'))

    return iteration


class Dataset():
    def __init__(self):
        ImageRoot = r'C:\Users\ASUS\Pose2Seg\data\coco2017\train2017'
        AnnoFile = r'C:\Users\ASUS\Pose2Seg\data\coco2017\annotations\person_keypoints_train2017_pose2seg.json'
        self.datainfos = CocoDatasetInfo(
            ImageRoot, AnnoFile, onlyperson=True, loadimg=True)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.datainfos)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        rawdata = self.datainfos[idx]
        img = rawdata['data']
        image_id = rawdata['id']

        height, width = img.shape[0:2]
        gt_kpts = np.float32(rawdata['gt_keypoints']).transpose(
            0, 2, 1)  # (N, 17, 3)
        gt_segms = rawdata['segms']
        gt_masks = np.array([annToMask(segm, height, width)
                             for segm in gt_segms])

        return {'img': img, 'kpts': gt_kpts, 'masks': gt_masks}

    def collate_fn(self, batch):
        batchimgs = [data['img'] for data in batch]
        batchkpts = [data['kpts'] for data in batch]
        batchmasks = [data['masks'] for data in batch]
        return {'batchimgs': batchimgs, 'batchkpts': batchkpts, 'batchmasks': batchmasks}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('===========> loading model <===========')
    model = Pose2Seg().cuda()
    # model.init("")
    model.train()

    logger.info('===========> loading data <===========')
    datasetTrain = Dataset()
    dataloaderTrain = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasetTrain, batch_size=1, shuffle=True,
                                                  num_workers=0, pin_memory=False,
                                                  collate_fn=datasetTrain.collate_fn)

    logger.info('===========> set optimizer <===========')
    ''' set your optimizer like this. Normally is Adam/SGD. '''
    #optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 0.0002, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
        model.parameters(), 0.0002, weight_decay=0.0000)

    iteration = 0
    epoch = 0
    try:
        while iteration < 14150*25:
            logger.info('===========>   training    <===========')
            iteration = train(model, dataloaderTrain,
                              optimizer, epoch, iteration)
            epoch += 1

            logger.info('===========>   testing    <===========')
            test(model, dataset='cocoVal', logger=logger.info)
            test(model, dataset='OCHumanVal', logger=logger.info)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt):
        logger.info('Save ckpt on exception ...')
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(
            SNAPSHOTDIR, 'interrupt_%d_%d.pkl' % (epoch, iteration)))
        logger.info('Save ckpt done.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU doesn't have enough memory. Try to reduce the batch size. If still the same, try to reduce input image size. It should work fine then.

By the way, for this type of model, 8GB of GPU memory is recommended.

Comment: Do you mean to split training data and put every part in folder and run it alone?

Comment: no, in your training code, you can find the batch size. batch_size=number of images your model will process together. More number of images need more memory. Reduce the batch size and train again.

Comment: but batch_size=1 Can I reduce it? please see train.py code up

Comment: if it's 1, that is the lowest possible. You can't reduce it. What is the input image size?

Comment: training data in coco dataset = 18 GB

Comment: no no, I'm asking about the model input shape. resolution of the images it's taking as the input.

Comment: How can I know it? if it is in train.py, please check the code above

Comment: resolution of the images is 300 horizontal resolution, 300 vertical resolution per image and there are 130K images in this dataset

Comment: how can I reduce the resolution?

Comment: Just resize all the images to some smaller size, let's say 150x150. And please change the model input shape similar to this. And if there is any pooling layer, you will need to change that too accordingly.